# making a multi-point curve(with equal length and degree of bend) from a parabola

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, logic

I am trying to create a multi-point curve following a parabolic arc. 
I have the arc height and base length. 
the only variable is X length of line segment 
5 degree of bend
parabola height of 1 meter
base length of 4 meters

I'am a bit rusty in my mathematical skills 
but I have tried theoretically from the given i have i could draw it into a graph points, thereby getting directrix, focus. while i am sure there is also a formula for arc length. 
but i cannot seem to find a formula for converting it into a multi-point curve/ multi-line curve

Comment: To me your question looks almost incomprehensible. Could you explain what is a multi-point curve or a multi-line curve?

Comment: Couldn't you insert a drawing ?

Comment: Do you mean by "multi-point curve" a Bezier curve or an equivalent ?

Comment: No answer to my questions ?